# pnacl debugging on Windows

Tags: windows, crash, google-nativeclient

I'm porting big c++ project to pnacl,
building on linux (centos7 x64) with pepper_40, using ppapi, ppapi_simple and nacl_io libraries.

in chrome on linux and macos, everything works.
on windows7-x64 chrome Version 42.0.2311.135 m - it crashes.

so I compiled debug (-g and -o0 flags ), but now browser fails to load unstripped pexe (nacl64,exe crashes):

NativeClient: PnaclCoordinator: Compile stream chunk failed. The PNaCl translator has probably crashed.

when loading stripped pexe and crashing the project, call stack I get is:

```
#0  0x000000000025a8f0 in Function468 ()
#1  0x0000000000387ea0 in Function2300 ()
#2  0x00000000001a45c0 in Function6270 ()
#3  0x00000000001a4560 in Function6269 ()
#4  0x00000000002b7d00 in Function6053 ()
#5  0x00000000003eca60 in Function8497 ()
#6  0x00000000000b5640 in Function8710 ()
#7  0x00000000000b55a0 in Function8709 ()
#8  0x00000000000b5520 in Function8708 ()
#9  0x00000000000b5440 in Function8707 ()
#10 0x00000000000b3860 in Function8525 ()
```

I tried to load unstripped version to dbg, after stripped one crashed, got same callstack.

How to debug it?

Comment: Are you using https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/devcycle/debugging#debugging-pnacl-pexes-pepper-35-or-later? Running chrome with --enable-nacl-debug, --no-sandbox, etc., using an NMF file that has "pnacl-debug"?

Do you mean that if you do that:

(1) You link to the unstripped pexe with "pnacl-debug", but that results in "NativeClient: PnaclCoordinator: Compile stream chunk failed."

(2) Otherwise, if you leave out "pnacl-debug" to force loading the "pnacl-translate" URL, you were able to translate, run, and attach with gdb, but that only gives the stripped stack trace?

Comment: This is the .nmf file:   {
  "program": {
    "portable": {
      "pnacl-translate": {
        "url": "proxylib_tester.pexe",
        "optlevel": 2
      },
      "pnacl-debug": {
              "url": "proxylib_tester.bc",
              "optlevel": 0
      }
    }
  }
}  , to load unstripped - i just remove the pnacl-debug section. Chrome cmd line:   chrome.exe  http://10.7.0.213:5103/ --allow-nacl-socket-api=10.7.0.213 --enable-nacl --enable-nacl-debug --no-sandbox --disable-hang-monitor

Comment: It would be nice to know why "Compile stream chunk failed." happens so that you can get debug info. However, something that could help you get unstuck is to use the "--no-strip-syms" flag with pnacl-finalize. Then your proxylib_tester.pexe will have the function names so at least the stack trace makes sense. How big is the .pexe? I'm wondering if "Compile stream chunk" is due to the compiler running out of memory. We're improving the memory usage: https://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/issues/detail?id=4063.

Comment: stripped - about 2MB
unstripped - over 50MB
i found the crash on windows, using printf and hours of logging.
Thanks